# Store form data in a list jsp

Tags: forms, list, jsp

I have a form that submits to a jsp page and i want to save data into a list whenever the user clicks on submit button, then display it on the jsp page. i tried `request.getParameter("submit")` but it always returns a null value and arraylist overwrites data. What should i do?

```
<form action="messages.jsp" target="msgframe" method="post" >
        <label for="entrer">Entrez votre message:</label>
        <input type="text" name="msg"/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Envoyer"/>
        <input type="reset" value="Quitter"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Don't you mean  request.getParameter("msg");  ?

Comment: No i mean request.getParameter("submit") so i can save the value of "msg" everytime the user clicks on submit button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to save the value of the typed message,

```
<input type="text" name="msg"/>
```

Use :

```
String msg = request.getParameter("msg")
```

Comment: @Mina, I corrected my answer (ther was a sily typo). You should give a try. The message should be in the msg variable